# How do i combine 2 Linq queries into 1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Parameter - (String Supplier)

```
var supplierID = db.SupplierTable
            .Where(m => m.SupplierName.Trim().ToLower() == Supplier.Trim().ToLower())
            .Select(m => m.SupplierID).First();

var supplierREFs = db.ProductSuppliers
            .Where(m => m.SupplierID == supplierID)
            .Select(m => m.SupplierRef);
```

can the above 2 queries be combined into 1 query?

Comment: join those two tables

Comment: Take your first query and put it in the second query where you have `supplierID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you need a sub-query:

```
Supplier = Supplier.Trim();  // do this once and not in the query

var supplierREFs = db.ProductSuppliers
    .Where(m => db.SupplierTable
        .Where(s => m.SupplierID == s.SupplierID)
        .Any(s => String.Equals(s.SupplierName.Trim(), Supplier, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
     )
    .Select(m => m.SupplierRef);
```

This query takes every `ProductSupplier` which `SupplierName` matches the given `Supplier`(ignoring the case). Then it returns it's `SupplierRef`.

Side-note: if you don't store `SupplierNames` with leading/trailing spaces in the database you should not compare with `s.SupplierName.Trim()` but `s.SupplierName`.

Comment: You missed the Trim() functionality of the original. More important would be which string-compare is convertable to SQL. Did you test this one (with EF)?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: i hope OP doesn't store the `SupplierNames` with leading or trailing spaces in the database. However, i have edited my code to include the trim. Yes, the `String.Equals` should be supported as far as what i've read. Of course i haven't tested it because i have no database to test.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Side-note: according to the database collation he would compare case insensitive anyway because that is the default. That also means, if he wants to change it it might not be sufficient to use `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` instead of `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. Then he really needs to either change the column COLLATE or use Linq-To-Objects (after case insensitive `Where`-filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can make it joining two entities like;

```
Supplier = Supplier.Trim().ToLower();

var supplierREFs = (from st in db.SupplierTable
                                join sr in supplierREFs on st.SupplierID equals sr.SupplierID
                                where 
                                st.SupplierName.Trim().ToLower() == Supplier
                                select sr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a one-to-many relationship between Supplier items from your SupplierTable and ProductSupplier items from ProductSuppliersTable:

Every Supplier has zero or more ProductSuppliers, and every ProductSupplier belongs to exactly one Supplier.

If you've configured your [one-to-many relationship according to the default entity framework conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) you'll have classes similar to the following:

```
class Supplier
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // Every Supplier has zero or more ProductSupplierTables:
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSuppierTable> ProductSupplierTables {get; set;}

    public string SupplierName {get; set;}
    ...
}

class ProductSupplier
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every ProductSupplier belongs to exactly one Supplier using foreign key
    public virtual Supplier Supplier {get; set;}
    public int SupplierId {get; set;}

    public string SupplierRef {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

It might be that some identifier names differ, but the Idea is clear: your Supplier needs a virtual ICollection of ProductSuppliers, and your ProductSupplier needs a foreign key to the Supplier as well as a virtual Supplier.

Once you've done this correctly, entity framework knows the primary keys and the foreign keys and create the correct tables for you.

The nice thing is that your DbContext and your DbSets know about this one-to-many relationship. Whenever you need Suppliers with their ProductSuppliers, you don't need to perform a join on foreign key. You can use the ICollection instead.

Rephrase for yourself what you want.

> I have the name of a supplier and I want the first Supplier items from
>   my SupplierTable that has a Trimmed LowerCase name that equals this
>   name, together with all the SupplierRefs from the supplier's
>   ProductSuppliers.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    string supplierName = Supplier.Trim().ToLower()
    dbContext.Suppliers
       .Where(supplier => String.ToLower(supplier.SupplierName) == supplierName)
       .Select(supplier => new
       {   // to improve performance: select only the properties you'll use
           SupplierId = supplier.Id,
           ...

           // select also all the SupplierRefs from its ProductSuppliers:
           SupplierRefs = supplier.ProductSupplier
               .Select(productSupplier => productSupplier.SupplierRef)
               .ToList(),
        })
        // I only want the First (or default) of these suppliers:
        .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Entity framework knows about your one-to-many, and which foreign key is used for this. Entity Framework will do the proper join and select for you.